# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when trying to run migration fresh seed

Tags: javascript, next.js, mikro-orm

I'm working on a nextJS project which uses mikro-orm , and I'm facing this error for days now:

```html
C:\Users\BossTrails\Documents\core.nest-main_2\node_modules\.bin\mikro-orm:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I get the error above when I try to run the comman - npm run migration:fresh:seed

Here is my package.json

```html
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start:server": "nest start --config nest-cli.server.json",
    "migration:fresh": "node node_modules/.bin/mikro-orm migration:fresh",
    "migration:fresh:seed": "node node_modules/.bin/mikro-orm migration:fresh --seed",
    "migration:init": "node node_modules/.bin/mikro-orm migration:create --initial",
    "migration:create": "node node_modules/.bin/mikro-orm migration:create",
    "migration:up": "node node_modules/.bin/mikro-orm migration:up",
    "migration:down": "node node_modules/.bin/mikro-orm migration:down",
    "migration:down:zero": "node node_modules/.bin/mikro-orm migration:down --to 0",
    "migration:rollout": "node node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./src/scripts/rollout-migrations",
    "start:server:dev": "nest start --config nest-cli.server.json --watch",
    "start:server:debug": "nest start --config nest-cli.server.json --debug --watch",
    "start:server:dist": "node dist/server",
    "start:worker": "nest start --config nest-cli.worker.json",
    "start:worker:dev": "nest start --config nest-cli.worker.json --watch",
    "start:worker:debug": "nest start --config nest-cli.worker.json --debug --watch",
    "start:worker:dist": "node dist/worker",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint \"{src,test}/**/*.ts\"",
    "lint:fix": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint \"{src,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^6.1.1",
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^5.1.1",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^5.1.1",
    "@mikro-orm/knex": "^5.0.0-dev.434",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^5.1.1",
    "@mikro-orm/nestjs": "^5.0.1",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^5.1.1",
    "@mikro-orm/reflection": "^5.1.1",
    "@mikro-orm/seeder": "^5.1.1",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^0.0.3",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.0.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/event-emitter": "^1.1.1",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^9.1.2",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.0.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^8.4.4",
    "@nestjs/platform-ws": "^8.4.4",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^1.0.2",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.1.4",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^8.4.4",
    "@svtslv/nestjs-ioredis": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.5.1",
    "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
    "amqp-ts": "^1.8.0",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.6.7",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.5.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1034.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "file-type": "^16.5.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.5.5",
    "ioredis": "^4.28.0",
    "nestjs-redis": "^1.3.3",
    "otp-generator": "^3.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "txtgen": "^2.2.8",
    "typedi": "^0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cron": "^1.7.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/faker": "^5.5.9",
    "@types/imagemin": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/imagemin-jpegtran": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/ioredis": "^4.27.8",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.176",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "useTsNode": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I've cleaned node packages
I've reinstalled npm and yarn
The same error I am getting with npm and yarn

I'm using:

windows 10
node version: 16.15.0
npm: 8.5.5

Comment: This doesn't sound like something SO can debug. Have you filed an issue on the [mikro-orm repo](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm), or looked over their current/closed issues?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a shell script with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

The problem was a windows issue. Windows had issues reading a bash file or something. But the whole set up works well on Linux or Mac.

So you can either switch to mac or linux.

OR

Use WSL ( the windows Linux distro). Install node and npm on the WSL , connect VS code to the WSL so that you can run and edit the code on VS code.

Run you scripts with the linux bash terminal which will now be set up in vs code